# Changing the background of UIWindow by importing image?

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm using this available sample code to create a simple app... The only thing I need to do is change the background to an image on my computer. The sample code I am using is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html). I don't know where and how I can implement the code I can use to set the background image (shown below). If someone could give some advice on how to incorporate the code below to the sample code I'm using, I would really appreciate it.

I'm trying to implement this code into the app code provided above:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BrainBrain.png"]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = background;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply place this two lines

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BrainBrain.png"]];
self.window.backgroundColor = background;
```

into the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions:` method of your `AppDelegate`

Comment: Warning: This will cause the image to be repeated instead of stretched -- just.. be aware :D

Comment: Yes, as the name suggests it will be treated like a pattern. Simply load an image of the screen dimensions.

Comment: ok, didnt get that but anyways the warning is just to make it clear for anybody -- this is the best way imo

Comment: When I try this I get the error: Property 'backgroundColor' cannot be found in forward class object 'PaintingWindow.' I'm not quite sure how to fix this... Advice?

Comment: you placed it in the wrong place. You should place it in your class implementing the `AppDelegate` protocol, which in your case appears to be `AppController`. Look for the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions` and add the lines there.

Comment: I can't find the line of code ur talking about. The closes thing I can find to what ur telling me is - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application

Comment: I'm looking in the AppController.m